# svn Can't find a temporary directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, temporary-files

When I want to checkout or update an svn reposity, I receive the error message

`svn: E020014: Can't find a temporary directory: Internal error`. This happens for all repositories I have on my system.

My hard drive is not full. I am using

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

and `svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)`.

The permission of my `/tmp` directory are `drwxrwxrwx  18 root root`. The system variables are set as follows:

```
> echo $TMPDIR 
/tmp
> echo $TMP
/tmp
> echo $TEMP
/tmp
```

I've tried reinstalling subversion and manually deleting the `.subversion` folder, but it didn't help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you check if the SVN repo's server (where it is hosted) has free space? This most likely happens because there is no space left on the server.

Comment: The server lets me create new repositories, I know no other methods for checking if the server is full

Comment: Where and how is your server hosted? Is it a linux server? If yes, try using the command `df -h`

Comment: The server is hosted at (https://svn.tugraz.at/svn). I don't know if it is a linux server, but it is highly unlikely that it is full, since hundreds of people are using it